# UIView mail-like staple animation

Tags: animation, uitableview, in-app-purchase

I want to implement a special animation and I'm wondering if somebody already did that.
Everybody knows this really cool staple effect form iPad mail, when selecting multiple mails.

I now want to bring that animation into my iPad app. I have a UITableView with available in-app purchases and I want the user to be able to buy multiple purchases at once.

The user can select multiple products in the tableView and I now want the images from the custom UITableViewCell to "staple together" with this really cool iPad like effect.

I also want the cells to move into this stack. This is my code (most probably I will experience performance issues with the photo from the cell):

```
- (IBAction)setEditingTableView:(id)sender
{
    if ([itemsTableView isEditing]) {
        for (NSIndexPath *cellPath in [itemsTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [itemsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];
            if ([cell isSelected]) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                    [[cell image] setFrame:[stackView frame]];
                    [[cell image] setCenter:[stackView center]];
                }];
            }
        }
        [itemsTableView setEditing:NO];
        [sender setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
    }
    else {
        [itemsTableView setEditing:YES];
        [sender setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
    }
}
```

[image]

Can anybody help?

Thanks, with kind regards, Julian

Comment: i was going to add a screenshot to the question. i don't know the iPad *staple effect*. i tried google-imaging it; but could not find it.

Comment: You'r right... I added a screenshot and some code already done.